# Prove equivalence: Internal Direct Sum of Modules (HW)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be a module and $M_1, M_2, M_3,..., M_n$ be submodules of $M$ verify that the following are equivalent:
>
> (1) $M$ is the internal direct sum of the $M_i$'s. (i.e. $M=M_1+M_2+M_3+...+M_n$)
>
> (2) each $m\in M$ can be expressed ***uniquely*** as $m=m_1+m_2+m_3+...+m_n$ with $m_i\in M_i$

Here are the things I know about modules so far:

The definition of a module and a submodule.

The definition of an internal direct sum given by:

> An R-Module $M$ is the internal direct sum of submodules $M_1, M_2, M_3,..., M_n$ if:
>
> $a)$ $M=M_1+M_2+M_3+...+M_n$
>
> $b)$ $M_i \cap \sum_{j\neq i} M_j = \{0\}$

I'm kind of stuck with this problem. Can I immediately assume that if $M=M_1+M_2+M_3+...+M_n$ , $m\in M$ can be expressed as $m=m_1+m_2+m_3+...+m_n$ with $m_i\in M_i$?

Any hint on how I could start this? I just need some ideas. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. $M=\sum M_i$ by definition means that every $m\in M$ can be expressed as $m=\sum m_i$. Now you can assume that for some $m\in M$ there are two such expressions and try to find contradiction with $b)$.

For the second implication again by definition if every $m$ has such expression then $M=\sum M_i$. Now assume that $b)$ is false and try to find contradiction with $(2)$.

You don't have to use proof by contradiction it's just a way i like to think about this.